# Auto-translate fetched result into navigator.language

Tags: javascript

There is my question, i've successfully fetched the RAWG api to retrieve information about latest video games.

Now the problem is that the game description result is in english only, so i have:

`this.game.description` that return the fetched description:

```
<p id="google_translate_element" class="card-text">Welcome to Yara, a tropical paradise frozen in time. As the dictator of Yara, Anton Castillo is intent on restoring his nation back to its former glory by any means, with his son, Diego, following in his bloody footsteps. Their oppressive rule has ignited a revolution.

JOIN THE REVOLUTION
Play as Dani Rojas, a local Yaran, and become a guerrilla fighter to liberate your nation.

YARA TORN APART
Fight against Anton's troops in the largest Far Cry playground to date across jungles, beaches, and Esperanza, the capital city of Yara.

GUERRILLA FIREPOWER
Employ makeshift weapons, vehicles, and animal companions to burn Anton's ruthless regime to the ground.</p>
```

is possible to translate this automatically (based maybe on navigator.language), or at least doing this only in ONE language?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "translate it automatically". Do you want that the RAWG API translate it for you? Or do you want to get the results from the API and then use another API to translate it (i.e. Google Translate)?

Comment: exaxcly, google translate can be good, but automatically, (no user intevention)

Comment: To cut straight to the chase, the Google Translate API is USD$20 per 1,000,000 of text, *however*, the first 500,000 characters per month are free. https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart

Comment: well, how can i translate this DIV with the free api from google?

Comment: @samaBARI that kind of question is not simply answered at a place like StackOverflow. You need to read the API documentation at https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/ and then do some tests to understand how it works. Finally, you can create your own system integration between your app and the google translate API. Perhaps you need to write the GTranslate API on your code (AKA wrapper). Just call the methods/functions that you wrote inside your code to fetch the translated text